# Changing mkdocs code blocks with a custom theme

Tags: html, markdown, mkdocs, custom-theme

I am trying to add some html elements (like a div) in a custom theme, that wrap the mkdocs generated code blocks from the html output.

mkdocs has their fenced code blocks with the triple backticks  ```` ``` stuff ``` ```` and when it produces the html output it creates `<pre><code (some stuff here)> stuff </pre></code>`. I was wondering if there is a way with custom themes that preserve the pre and code tags output  with the `highlight.js` class attribute but also allow me to wrap it in a custom `div` so that I can put the code blocks in a container with some other elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code blocks are generated by the Markdown parser, not by the MkDocs template. In fact the HTML generated from Markdown for a page is passed to the template as a single block. Therefore, to alter the HTML output by Markdown, you need to use a Markdown extension. MkDocs uses [Python-Markdown](https://python-markdown.github.io) and fully [supports](https://www.mkdocs.org/user-guide/configuration/#markdown_extensions) Python-Markdown [extensions](https://python-markdown.github.io/extensions/).

If one exists, you could use an existing [third party extension](https://github.com/Python-Markdown/markdown/wiki/Third-Party-Extensions) which provides the desired behavior. Alternatively, you could [create your own](https://python-markdown.github.io/extensions/api/) custom extension.

Comment: thanks for the tip! I just ended up writing a plugin for mkdocs to do what I needed to do. I used the `on_post_page` override to do so.